Junit5 is running all tests if the tag is not matched
I have been fighting with this problem for the last 2 days and I did not manage to find a solution for it.
I'm trying to do a Gradle task to run some integration tests using Tags and ScalaTest.
If my test class as any test with a tag that matches the includeTags it works as expected only running those tests. But the problem is when no test on the class includes this tag. In that case it runs all tests when it should run none. The same logic occurs when I do excludeTags '!DontRun'
Do you by any change know what might be the issue?
My current configuration looks like this:
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines 'scalatest'
        excludeTags 'DontRun'
        testLogging {
            events("passed", "skipped", "failed", "standard_error")
        }
    }
    description = 'This should run all tests that are not tagged as DontRun'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } // Disable task caching
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines 'scalatest'
        includeTags 'DontRun'
         testLogging {
            events("passed", "skipped", "failed", "standard_error")
     }
    }
    description = 'Run all tests marked with DontRun'
}

With my Tags being defined with:
test("expensive test", Tag("DontRun"))(actualTest())

Where test comes from the AsyncFunSuiteLike from scalatest
